# play s3 amazon video on facebook application

Tags: facebook, amazon-s3

I have uploaded video on s3 amazonws and now I want to play these video on face book.

I am using

```
<fb:swf swfbgcolor="000000"
swfsrc='player.swf?file=http://s3.amazonws.com/bucketname/key&image='
 imgsrc=''
width='550' height='350'/>
```

Does anybody know about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead used **fb:flv** if all videos are in FLV format.

```
<fb:flv src='http://s3.amazonws.com/bucketname/key' width='165' height='127' title='my movie' color='#FFBB00' salign='r'  scale='showall'/>";
```